# The type or namespace name `Multimedia' could not be found (monodevelop)

Tags: .net, mono

I am compiling a .Net project on Linux, using monodevelop.

I get the following error:

The type or namespace name `Multimedia' could not be found.

Which .Net library contains the Multimedia namespace, and what is its mono equivalent

**[Edit]**

I am having the same problem with a reference System.Deployment - which seems to be missing

What is the mono equivalent for System.Deployment (and which library contains that namespace?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Deployment.Internal` exists as can be seen in the Mono docs [here](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=N%3aSystem.Deployment.Internal).

[System.Deployment.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.aspx) does not seem to exist in Mono, but seems to be just for ClickOnce customization, so unless you need ClickOnce, you might be able to just remove any code that uses those classes.

I don't do Multimedia much so I'm not sure, but I can't remember seeing that namespace in the framework. Are you sure that that's not some other component/library that your project is using?

Comment: Meh, turns out that the Multimedia lib was not been used after all. I removed it and all is well now. Tx